# How do I stop Android ListView from resetting values after scrolling?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a ListView with a custom adapter, and each row contains a seekbar the user can set. Each seekbar has a seekBarChangeListener which is set in the adapter, and when a user changes the value of the seekbar in the ListView, the adapter's arraylist is updated. This is what I've got in `getView()` of the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.contentView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pref_content);
        viewHolder.sliderView = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.pref_slider);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    // Get initial values
    Prompt p = promptList.get(position);
    String content = p.getContent();
    int sliderLevel = p.sliderLevel();

    // Set views with initial values
    viewHolder.contentView.setText(content);
    viewHolder.sliderView.setMax(noOfLevels);
    viewHolder.sliderView.setProgress(sliderLevel);

    // Set Change Listener for Seekbar
    viewHolder.sliderView.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            // Set new level of the Slider in the Array List
            promptList.get(position).setSliderLevel(progress);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

So when the user changes the value of the seekbar the ChangeListener gets the object from the ArrayList and sets its new sliderLevel value. However, if I set a new value in the ListView and then scroll down the up again, so that getView is called again, the seekbar returns to its initial value, even though I have changed the value in the arrayList.

Can someone help show me where I'm going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: You should create a separate list to save the value of each seekbar, and set to the corresponding value in the getView method. Listview recycle the view

Comment: ListView recycles the view, but the adapter maintains the same ArrayList throughout. When the view is recycled, getView() is called again, which accesses the same ArrayList. So if I change the ArrayList, once getView() is called again, it should display the new value.

Comment: Yeah you'r right, that's strange

Comment: I'd try to add a call to `viewHolder.sliderView.setMax(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `onProgressChanged()` will be called every time the user changes the `SeekBar` value. But it will also be called "by system" (I think this happens because the `SeekBar` is recycled as part of the convertView). That's why it is necessary to check whether `fromUser` is true:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (!fromUser) return;

    // Set new level of the Slider in the Array List
    promptList.get(position).setSliderLevel(progress);
}
```

In your case, you do not have to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` because as long as one specific `SeekBar` is still shown, only the user will change its progress. Once it is hidden (because the user scrolls) and the data for this position have to be shown again later, `getView()` will be called and the correct value will be set to the `SeekBar` in the convertView which happens to display your data then.

One other thought (performance reasons): consider only changing the progress value of `promptList.get(position)` as soon as the user stops manipulating the slider. For this, you can override `onStopTrackingTouch()` instead of `onProgressChanged()` and write

```
 promptList.get(position).setSliderLevel(seekBar.getProgress());
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I answered my own question with roughly the same solution, but I'll accept this answer as this is what was causing most of the issues with my ListView. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to solve the issue by moving `promptList.get(position).setSliderLevel(progress)` from `onProgressChanged()` to `onStopTrackingTouch()` in the seekbar's `OnSeekBarChangeListener()`, and also changing the height of the ListView from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`. Both of these things were causing undersirable behaviour.

For some reason onProgressChanged() was being called at runtime, without touching the seekbar at all, even though the changeListener is being set after initialising the seekbar with a value from the arrayList.

Edit: 0X0nosugar's answer explains this behaviour

Comment: can you tell  me what's the serSliderLevel() is doing and where is placed?